# check if a file is an ORC file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, orc

I have a program with input expected to have an ORC file format.

I want to be able to check if the provided input is effectively an ORC file. Checking extension only is not enough because the user can omit the extension.

For Parquet for example, we can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569678/how-to-detect-parquet-files) if the first line contains "PAR1".

Is there an equivalent way for ORC ?

Comment: Check the necessary hex BITs in the beginning of file? and see if BITs matches what you require? In bash could also do: `cat file.orc | head -1 | grep 'PAR1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @Ed Elliott, ORC file contains the information in its tail. The 3 bytes before the last byte of an ORC file contain "ORC". Here is the code that did it for me:

```scala
val mainPath = Paths.get(new URI(path)).toString
val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(3)
val channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(mainPath), StandardOpenOption.READ)
channel.read(buffer, channel.size - 4)
new String(buffer.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).equals("ORC")
```

Something that is worth mentionning is that time complexity of this read is O(1) provided that the number of bytes you will read is constant. So read won't iterate over the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly they have a similar thing to parquet files with the magic string ORC but it is at the end of the file.

https://orc.apache.org/specification/ORCv0/

Finishing one byte before the end of the file is the Postscript, the last three bytes of the Postscript are ORC so you should read the last 4 bytes which should be ORC something.

I would use a hex editor to validate this!